# The argument type 'Stream<List<MovieModel>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<List>'.Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I am adding items to a list in firestore.
But when I try to read items from DB using a stream:
The argument type 'Stream<List>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream'.
dbservice.dart

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});
  List<MovieModel> _movieFromDocumentSnapshot(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    return documentSnapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return MovieModel(
          original_title: doc.data()['original_title'],
          overview: doc.data()['overview'],
          poster_path: doc.data()['poster_path'],
          id: doc.data()['id'],
          country: doc.data()['country'],
          release_date: doc.data()['release_date'],
          run_time: doc.data()['run_time'],
          genre: doc.data()['genre'],
          rating: doc.data()['rating'].toDouble());
    }).toList();
  }

  Stream<List<MovieModel>> get movies {
    return showCollection
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('movies')
        .snapshots()
        .map(_movieFromDocumentSnapshot);
  }
}
```

Getting data from stream:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<AppUser>(context);
    print(user.uid);
    return StreamBuilder<List<MovieModel>>(
        stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).movies,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return SafeArea(..
```

Comment: did you try to declare your StreamBuilder as such: StreamBuilder<List> ?

Comment: yes. It says Stream<List<dynamic>> cant be assigned to parameter type  Stream<List>